# Target a specific element inside of the div that was click without using jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have a list of items in which I would like to listen for which item was clicked on and change the CSS for an inner div in that item.

```
var inactiveItems = document.getElementsByClassName('inactive');

for (var i = 0; i < inactiveItems.length; i++) {
  inactiveItems[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
}

function handleClick(e) {
  var width = document.body.clientWidth;
  console.log(e.target);
  if (width < 960) {
    e.target.style.top = '0px';
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<li class="days_item days_item inactive"">
  <span>19</span>
  <div class="locked-item"></div>
</li>
```

I would like to change the CSS on the `.locked-item` inside the event target, not the target itself.

Comment: Your initial description is valid, but please, can you express it without two levels of nested propositions to make it *obvious* that the sentence is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than accessing [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) (which is the clicked element), access [`e.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) in order to get the element that the event listener was originally attached to. Then you can select the child `.locked-item` by chaining `.querySelector('.locked-item')`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/80ete9hg/)

```
function handleClick(e) {
    var width = document.body.clientWidth,
        day = e.currentTarget,
        lockedItem = day.querySelector('.locked-item');

    if (width < 960 && lockedItem !== null) {
        lockedItem.style.top = '0px';
    }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted because it's a good solution, but I wonder if someone who's only ever known jQuery will understand DOM event propagation to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `this.getElementsByClassName('locked-item')[0]` to select that `<div>`.

```js
var inactiveItems = document.getElementsByClassName('inactive');

for (var i = 0; i < inactiveItems.length; i++) {
  inactiveItems[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
}

function handleClick(e){
  var width = document.body.clientWidth;
  console.log(e.target);
  if (width < 960) {
    e.target.style.top = '0px';
  }
  this.getElementsByClassName('locked-item')[0].style.background = 'yellow';
}
```

```html
<li class="days_item days_item inactive">
  <span>19</span>
  <div class="locked-item">x</div> <!-- I added some text, just so you see the div -->
</li>
```

Read up:

- [`this` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [`.getElementsByClassName()` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)